# Select all columns with same name from different tables

Tags: sql-server, ssms, union

I have 4 tables. In 3 of these, there are a column named ACTIVE_FL which can have a value of "Y" or "N".

How can I select, from all tables only the columns ACTIVE_FL which have as value "N" ?

I tried UNION but the result was not as expected.

I am using SQL Server and SSMS.

EDIT: that's an example of my db

[image: example]

What I would like to obtain is a SELECT of all the cells with 'N' as value along with corresponding table name and id:

[image]

Comment: try UNION ALL. UNION will remove duplicates, which is likely why your result set was not as expected

Comment: Please include the definitions of the tables in question, and the result you are expecting.

Comment: @HeinrichSmit added few details

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
--Setup demo data
declare @T1 TABLE (ACTIVE CHAR(1), ID INT, OTHER VARCHAR(5))
declare @T2 TABLE (ACTIVE CHAR(1), ID INT, OTHER VARCHAR(5))
declare @T3 TABLE (ACTIVE CHAR(1), ID INT, OTHER VARCHAR(5))
declare @T4 TABLE (ACTIVE CHAR(1), ID INT, OTHER VARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @T1(ACTIVE,ID,OTHER) VALUES
('Y',1,'ABC'),('Y',2,'ABC'),('N',3,'ABC')

INSERT INTO @T2(ACTIVE,ID,OTHER) VALUES
('Y',1,'ABC'),('N',2,'ABC'),('N',3,'ABC')

INSERT INTO @T3(ACTIVE,ID,OTHER) VALUES
('Y',1,'ABC'),('Y',2,'ABC'),('Y',3,'ABC')

INSERT INTO @T4(ACTIVE,ID,OTHER) VALUES
('N',1,'ABC'),('N',2,'ABC'),('Y',3,'ABC')

--The actual select code
SELECT 'TAB1' AS TABLE_NAME, ACTIVE, ID FROM @T1 WHERE ACTIVE = 'N'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TAB2' AS TABLE_NAME, ACTIVE, ID FROM @T2 WHERE ACTIVE = 'N'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TAB3' AS TABLE_NAME, ACTIVE, ID FROM @T3 WHERE ACTIVE = 'N'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TAB4' AS TABLE_NAME, ACTIVE, ID FROM @T4 WHERE ACTIVE = 'N'
```

---

```
| TABLE_NAME | ACTIVE | ID |
|------------|--------|----|
| TAB1       | N      | 3  |
| TAB2       | N      | 2  |
| TAB2       | N      | 3  |
| TAB4       | N      | 1  |
| TAB4       | N      | 2  |
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can change the example above to use a sub-query, which means you only need to change your predicate in one place:

```
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT 'TAB1' AS TABLE_NAME, ACTIVE, ID FROM @T1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'TAB2' AS TABLE_NAME, ACTIVE, ID FROM @T2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'TAB3' AS TABLE_NAME, ACTIVE, ID FROM @T3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'TAB4' AS TABLE_NAME, ACTIVE, ID FROM @T4
    )A
    WHERE A.ACTIVE = 'N'
```